# QImage padding - any function availavble?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qimage

Is there any function which I can use in order to pad my QImage object?
I have tried to search over the net unsuccefuly.
Thx in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "qimage.h"
#include <QImage>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QColor>
#include "qcolor.h"
#include <Qdebug>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Init!");
    qDebug() << "C++ Style Debug Message";
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    int height;
    int width;
    unsigned char *p, *p_begin;
    QImage img("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pictures\\2013-09-26\\IMG_0836.JPG");
    height = img.height();
    width = img.width();
    p = (unsigned char *)malloc(height * width * sizeof(unsigned char));
    p_begin = p;

    qDebug() << "Begin For Loop";
    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; ++col)
    {
        QColor clrCurrent( img.pixel( col, row ));
        *p = (unsigned char)((clrCurrent.green() * 0.587) + (clrCurrent.blue() * 0.114) + (clrCurrent.red() * 0.299));
        p++;
    }
}

qDebug() << "Finished First Loop!";
p = p_begin;
for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < width; ++col)
    {
        QColor clrCurrent(img.pixel(col, row));
        clrCurrent.setBlue((int)(*p));
        clrCurrent.setGreen((int)(*p));
        clrCurrent.setRed((int)(*p));
        img.setPixel(col, row, clrCurrent.rgba());
        p++;
    }
}

QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap);
scene.addItem(item);
view.show();

return a.exec();
 }
```

Hi I edited my question, i added my code in order to give you more feeling of what is going on. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to pad my qimage with the same  boudary pixels.

Comment: Is that make sese?

Comment: I mean, what do you want to do with the pad of the image? Do you want to paint it to what, use it on scene, label, or what? Or do you want to save it? What is the purpose of adding pad?

Comment: I want to make computations (sliding window of 5x5) on the image's pixels. This way I need to pad my QImage picture in order to execute this computation. the padding would be just duplication of the boundaty pixels. finally i would like to display it to the screen. I am using scene.

Comment: So you want to slide your image, example from -image.width to 0 right?
You can paint it manually, using the painter and you can use the clip to cut the painting.

Comment: So you want your QGraphicsPixmapItem slide from left to right?

Comment: @DanielEitan - just use an image editor and post an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QImage` offers no way to change its size. You need to create a new, larger image, erase its contents, start a `QPainter` on it, then draw the source image in the center of the new image. That way you'll have padding.

Below is a function that returns a padded version of the image, with a given color used for padding, and a test harness for it.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/image-pad-35968431
#include <QtGui>

template <typename T>
QImage paddedImage(const QImage & source, int padWidth, T padValue) {
  QImage padded{source.width() + 2*padWidth, source.height() + 2*padWidth, source.format()};
  padded.fill(padValue);
  QPainter p{&padded};
  p.drawImage(QPoint(padWidth, padWidth), source);
  return padded;
}

int main() {
   QImage source{64, 64, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
   source.fill(Qt::red);
   auto padded = paddedImage(source, 16, Qt::blue);
   padded.save("test.png");
}
```

Output:

[image: the generated padded image]